# Как сделать парсер файла для телеграм бота

Tags: python, html, telegram-bot

Как сделать что то типа парсера, но только не текст, а файла.
Суть в том, что пользователь отправляет файл, а потом этот файл обрабатывается на одном сайте с нейросетью и кидает этот уже готовый файл пользователю. Можно ли так сделать вообще. Просто  я на ютубе смотрел там ток с текстом работают.

если что файл - аудио

Comment: Получи файл у пользователя, отправь этот же файл череp api на сайт. В чем вопрос сам? Зачем файл парсить?

Comment: А проблема то в чем? Получайте от пользователя любой файл какой можно передать и делайте с ним что угодно, по готовности высылайте обратно.

Comment: ну проблема как бы в том что я не знал наверно не, спасибо